# Roblox "Secure Channel Support" Error 0x8007sf7d

Tags: ssl, wine

<strike>Not to sure really where to ask this, but here it goes;</strike>

With the new 6.11 version of wine, Roblox is now (mostly) working on Linux. Despite that, I have had some of my own issues when trying to use Roblox. When I first run the installer via wine on my Arch machine, I get an error saying that "HttpSendRequest failed"..."An error occured in the secure channel support (0x80072f7d)".

[image]

Doing a little bit of DuckDuckGo-fu... then Google-fu... has lead me into the vast deserts of the internet, where most results are just "How to" phishing pages. Unfortunately, another error goes by the same code for the <strike>Windows</strike> Microsoft Store, so searching for help specifically on Roblox is... very hard.

I *believe* the issue has *something* to do with TLS or SSL, but I'm not aware of any central place to change those settings, especially not on Arch Linux. To assist in finding out what the issue is, here are a few details about my PC.

- Distro: Arch Linux x86_64
- Kernel: 5.12.11-arch1-1
- Wine: 6.11-1
- Networking: extra/networkmanager 1.32.0-1
- IP Address: Static
- WM (May be useful?????????): community/i3-gaps 4.19.1-1
- Brain: Blown

As far as I know I'm the only person on the planet to have found this error outside of [one other person on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/roblox/comments/g0d7m2/rroblox_weekly_question_thread_for_april_13_2020/fneo9i4?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3). Hope this doesn't end up having a painfully obvious solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, ended up being a painfully obvious solution. Wine reports something like this;
[image]
And if you install the package corresponding to the thing it says is missing (multilib/lib32-gnutls) everything works juuuuuusssstt fine.

As always I hope that in exchange for my embarrassment someone will find this useful.

Comment: Thank you for posting this issue and your answer! I ran into the same thing on Ubuntu 21.10.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running into this same issue on Ubuntu (I'm using 21.10), I solved it by installing the 32-bit gnutls library with the following:

```
sudo apt install libgnutls30:i386
```